# Cycle for and mvtnorm?

Tags: r, cycle

I need to combine a cycle for with the function mvtnorm.
With pmvnorm this can easily done:for example here I create a vector with the different value of the cumulative probability according to different value of the mean:

```
a <- c(0, 0, 0)
y <- c(0, 0, 0)
for(i in 1:3)
a[i] <- i*0.5
for(i in 1:3)
y[i] <- pnorm(2, a[i], 1)
y
# [1] 0.9331928 0.8413447 0.6914625
```

But what about if I use `mvtnorm`? I would like to have a vector of the probabilities of a bivariate with the mean of one of the two distribution that takes different value. How do I write the command mu? For example

```
library(mvtnorm)
a <- c(0, 0, 0)
for(i in 1:3)
a[i] <- i*0.5
mu <- c(0, 0)
for(i in 1:2)
mu[i] <- (1, a)
```

...and so on. I'm blocked with the command mu. Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: You seem to struggle with vectorization. The first six lines can be replaced by `pnorm(2,0.5*1:3,1)`. In the second block, it's not clear what you want to calculate. Please, give more details. Which function you want to call? With which parameters?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of the first block. Concerning the second one, I report a simple example that maybe make easier the explanation: library(mvtnorm)
m<-2
corr<-diag(2)
corr[2,1]<-0
y=pmvnorm(mean=c(2,2*1:3),corr,lower=c(10,-Inf), upper=c(+Inf,10)). I want a vector y(a,b,c) where a is the cumulative probability when the mean of the second distribution is 2, b the same with the mean equal to 4 and c when the mean is equal to 6

Comment: You should edit your question with this additional info. Try `vapply(2*1:3,function(x) pmvnorm(mean=c(2,x),corr,lower=c(10,-Inf), upper=c(+Inf,10)),1)` (not sure, still not completely clear to me).

Comment: Great, it works!!!! Thanks a lot. The command vapply is exactly what I was looking for and I didn't know its existence

Comment: One last think: If I want to change simultaneously the mean of both distribution with two different function, how do I use the vapply command?for ex  vapply(2*1:3,function(x); 1*1:3,function(y) pmvnorm(mean=c(y,x),corr,lower=c(10,-Inf), upper=c(+Inf,10)),1)